# Will i lose device storage if i get a new screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

Last night I dropped my phone on the bathroom floor, there is a tiny crack in the top left corner, but now my screen wont work. Phone rings, home button lights up but screen is dead. If I take the screen to get fixed, will I lose photo's I didn't have stored on my SD card?

Answer (score 0):

No, the screen and board should be different assemblies, so they should be able to replace just the screen only.